# Mysql SQL Query Across 2 Tables - Not Sure How to Do It Properly

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have 2 tables set up like this (irrelevant rows omitted):

```
> product
  - id
  - user_id

> thread
  - id
  - prod_id
  - user_id
  - due_date
```

now I want to create a query that picks all rows from thread table that either:

1. have a thread.user_id of (for example) "5"
2. have a prod_id where the product.user_id is "5"

I am assuming there is a way to do this, something like ...

```
SELECT 
    thread.due_date 
FROM
    product, thread 
WHERE 
    thread.user_id='5' 
OR 
    // not sure how to finish it
```

Up to this point, I would just use PHP to do this, but would really like to kick up my SQL knowledge a notch and get this working via SQL if possible.

Thanks -

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use an outer join to do this:

```
SELECT thread.* FROM thread 
LEFT OUTER JOIN product
ON thread.prod_id = product.id
WHERE thread.user_id = 5 OR product.user_id = 5
```

A problem you might find is that you could get duplicate threads if a thread has a user id 5 but also a product with user id 5. Not sure if that will be an issue in your case though. You may be able to use `SELECT DISTINCT` to remove these (thanks  Alex Martelli)

Comment: If potential duplication is a problem, `SELECT DISTINCT` rather than plain `SELECT` may help.

Comment: Combined with the SELECT DISTINCT idea, this worked exactly as I needed - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

```
SELECT t.due_date
FROM thread t
INNER JOIN product p ON p.id = t.prod_id
WHERE t.user_id = 5 OR p.user_id = 5
```

**Edit:**
My example is using the SQL 92 standard.  If you'd like to stick with the SQL-89 style join from your original post you can do something like:

```
SELECT thread.due_date
FROM product, thread
WHERE product.id = thread.prod_id
AND (thread.user_id = 5 OR product.user_id = 5)
```

However, check out [Beginning MySQL](http://books.google.com/books?id=TFrbhHHxuXUC&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=sql+92+89+standards&source=bl&ots=tgTnvQOFwl&sig=-fGy033WxWkduiqIbTtIArqo4Sk&hl=en&ei=uAwcSpFboOG2B6WQoegM&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=10) - it has some good information about the two standards.

Comment: If you use an inner join, you will only get back threads which have a corresponding product

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT thread.* LEFT OUTER JOIN product ON thread.prod_id=product.id WHERE thread.user_id=5 OR product.user_id=5;
```

I'm not sure about the SELECT thread.* but it makes sense since that table.* stuff works when GRANTing privileges.